# Check a vector before clear?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, stdvector

I'm not sure, but I think I've read that you should only delete a vector if it's not empty.
So now I always check before I delete a vector:

```
if (!vector.empty()) {
    vector.clear();
}
```

However, I no longer find anything about whether this step is unnecessary.

Is it forbidden to use `clear` on an empty vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, there was an [issue](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue151) related to the undefined behavior while clearing out an empty sequences or associative containers but this is fixed now and it is **perfectly safe** to call `std::vector::clear` **without** previously checking if the `std::vector` is empty.

Answer (score 4):

The check is unneeded,

and decrease readability IMO.